# How to insert empty row at the table based on condition in case using JRBeanCollectionDataSource?

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans

There is a list and I use this mechanism to pass it to my jasper report:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
```

The Object of that list is as follows:

```
public class Test{
  private int id;
  //other properties  + getters & setter
}
```

Now Assume I have 10 elements within my list (id= 1 to 10) and I want to separate them in one table using an empty row, meaning 5 rows top, one empty row, 5 rows down.

How to do that ?

Comment: @AlexK where should I put the page breaker ? on the table cell ?

Comment: @AlexK the attached link does not help out ...

Answer (score 1):

The *subreport* element can helps with solving this problem - we can show or hide subreport based on condition using *printWhenExpression*.

In your case we need to show subreport with one empty line.

#### Example

The subreport for showing empty line is very simple. It does not need datasource for showing data - we can put *staticText* right at *Title* band. We don't need also margins.

The *jrxml* will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Empty Line" pageWidth="572" pageHeight="30" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="572" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <style name="bordered">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="bordered" x="0" y="0" width="572" height="30"/>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

I used simple *csv* datasource for example - file *films.csv* contains data for report:

```
id,name,year,rating
1,The Shawshank Redemption,1994,9.3
2,The Godfather,1972,9.2
3,The Dark Knight,2008,9.0
4,The Godfather: Part II,1974,9.0
5,The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King,2003,8.9
6,Pulp Fiction,1994,8.9
7,Schindler's List,1993,8.9
8,"The Good, the Bad and the Ugly",1966,8.9
9,12 Angry Men,1957,8.9
10,Avengers: Endgame,2019,8.8
```

The main (master) report is using *CSV File* Data Adapter for building report.

The *jrxml* of master report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Insert blank row on condition" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" >
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="films.csv"/>
    <style name="bordered">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="year" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="rating" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="158" y="0" width="256" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Films. Showing empty line for Id == 5]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="70" y="0" width="290" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="360" y="0" width="69" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Year]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="429" y="0" width="143" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Rating]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="60">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="572" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" >
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{id} == 5]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["empty_row.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="bordered" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="bordered" x="70" y="0" width="290" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="bordered" x="360" y="0" width="69" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{year}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="bordered" x="429" y="0" width="143" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{rating}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I used `<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{id} == 5]]></printWhenExpression>` for hiding subreport with empty line, it means that empty line will show only of row with `id == 5`. You can use any expression you want.

The output at JSS will be:

[image: The output at JSS]

#### Alternative solutions

- You can insert element during building collection before passing this collection at *JRBeanCollectionDataSource*.
- You can implement custom DataSource based on *JRBeanCollectionDataSource* with some logic.